# Catch-all for non-existing users doesn't work (Postfix)

Tags: centos, postfix

The catch-all works well for existing mailboxes, but not for random mailboxes. What is wrong?

Sending to a non-existing mailbox gives (`/etc/log/maillog`):

```
Dec 27 23:09:42 vps40198 postfix/smtpd[18623]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-oa0-f47.google.com[209.85.219.47]: 550 5.1.1 <random@fake.tld>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table; from=<fake@gmail.com> to=<random@fake.tld> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-oa0-f47.google.com>
```

My mail server being at `fake.tld` and `random` being the non-existing user.

These are the relevant `/etc/postfix/*.cf` files:

```
#mysql-domains.cf
host = localhost
user = postfix
password = xxxx
dbname = postfix
query = SELECT 1 FROM domain WHERE domain = '%s'

#mysql-email2email.cf
host = localhost
user = postfix
password = xxxx
dbname = postfix
query = SELECT username FROM user WHERE username = '%s'

#mysql-forwards.cf
host = localhost
user = postfix
password = xxxx
dbname = postfix
query = SELECT dst FROM forward WHERE src = '%s'

#mysql-mailboxes.cf
host = localhost
user = postfix
password = xxxx
dbname = postfix
query = SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(username,'@',-1),'/mail/',username,'/') FROM user WHERE username = '%s'
```

The domain for the user exists in the database.

What is wrong?

#### EDIT:

I suppose it needs a directory to save its mail to, how would I redirect mail but not save them to disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared I used virtual_mailbox_alias_maps instead of virtual_alias_maps. The former doesn't exist but Postfix didn't complain. No idea how this came to be, maybe some faulty guide or my own mistyping.